# merge some columns in a bigger table

Tags: r, dataframe

I've been trying for days to put the content (character) of several columns into one column and tried gather and more.
Attached is my example: 5 columns, two of them I want to merge (D1 and D2). If I run the script, the merged column (S) contains the normal values (singular), for the other columns the values are doubled (since two columns are merged). In the original dataset, there are several columns that I want to merge and the remaining values are each multiplied by the number of columns that are being merged.
Does anyone have any advice for me on how to get simple values in the remaining columns as well?

Thanks in advance

```css
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("tidyverse")



data4 <- data.frame(B = c("A1", "NA", "A2", "A3", "NA", "A5", "A1"), C = c("NA", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A5", "A5"),
                  D1 = c("A2", "A3", "A1", "NA", "A2", "A5", "A5"), D2 = c("NA", "A3", "A2","A1", "A4", "A3", "NA"), E = c("A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A1"))



for (i in 1:5) {
  data4[,i] <- as.vector(data4[,i ])
}; rm(i) 


data5 <- gather(data4, S1, S, D1:D2)     
data6 <- select(data5, B, C, S, E)

data7 <- stack(as.vector(data6[1:14,])) 
data8 <- data7[!is.na(data7$values), ] 

data9 <- (table(data7))   
data10 <-  prop.table(data9) 

df <- data.frame (data9, data10)
df1 <- df[ , c('Values.1, ind.1')] <- list(NULL) 

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=ind, y=Freq.1, fill=ind)) +
  geom_bar(colour="black", stat="identity", position=position_dodge2())+
  geom_text(aes(label = Freq), vjust = 0)+
  theme_classic()
```

[Find the current output here. But every value except the ones for S should be half the value. Supposed values for B: 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flqk1.png)

Comment: Can you post the current output and draw the expected output?

Comment: I added a picture... so every bar in the pic should be half the length (except S, S has the right values). For better understanding I added the numbers of values as well. Ask anytime if you have more questions.